# for loop in remote host is not working - shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
ssh $hname "cd /opt/tomcat/webapps/aware/WEB-INF/classes/com && for FNAME in `tar tvf /tmp/prop.tar | awk '{print $6}'` 
do
  if test ! -s "/tmp/$fname/prop_bkup.tar"
  then
    ls $FNAME && tar cvf /tmp/$fname/prop_bkup.tar $FNAME && rm $FNAME || echo "$FNAME is a new file".
  else
    ls $FNAME && tar uvf /tmp/$fname/prop_bkup.tar $FNAME && rm $FNAME || echo "$FNAME is a new file".
  fi
done"
```

Above for loop is not working in remote host. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited you question to put the code into a code block.  In the mean time, I can see a few  potential problems:

1. Use single quotes around the main command to prevent your local
   shell filling in the variables.  This will also be causing problems
   with the double quotes in the remote command.
   If you change to single quotes, you'll need to make sure you've still quoted the `awk` argument properly.
2. You've used both lowercase `$fname` and uppercase `$FNAME` - they should all be the same (`$FNAME` in this instance).

You need to explain what you mean by "not working".  This will give you much better answers.

Comment: Hi , Cant we execute this same loop by using command file in remote host, I mean write the loop from local by using echo command and execute at remote host

Comment: If you want to, but the same issues arise.  You'd be better off writing a local file with the script you want to run, then using scp to copy it to the remote host, then executing it via ssh.

Comment: Hi i hav done below modifications and it is working fine. Thanks for the support given.